# Change the language of the Fullcalendar React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, locale

I cannot find on the fullcalendar documentation how to set the locale for the React component (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react).

This is how I'm using the component:

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react' // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid' // a plugin!

export default function Calendar(props){
    
    return (
        <Box>
            <FullCalendar
            plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            />
        </Box>
    );

}
```

How can I set the language to Spanish?

Answer (score 15):

The locale can be set on the Fullcalendar React component like this:

1. Run: `yarn add @fullcalendar/core`
2. Import the locale: `import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es';`
3. Pass the locale as a prop to the component:

   ```
    <FullCalendar locale={esLocale} plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]} initialView="dayGridMonth" />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer of [Agu Dondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936703/agu-dondo), you can import all languages available.

```
import allLocales from '@fullcalendar/core/locales-all'
```

And later, to the component `FullCalendar`, add `locales` and in `locale` use the abbreviation language like `es` or `ca`.

```
<FullCalendar locales={allLocales} locale={'es'} plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]} initialView="dayGridMonth" />
```